# Monadic space library? A vector of coordinates wrapped in a monad of unspecified type?

Tags: haskell, monads

This must exist, right? It seems to me that points in mathematical spaces are often made to carry extra baggage. In my case, I'd like to label each point in an n-dimensional space with a name and a domain-specific type. Is a monad the right way to represent such extra baggage, or is a parameterized record the best way to do it? And what libraries provide this sort of capability out of box?

Comment: Can you provide an example type and Monad instance for what you're imagining? What do you expect bind to do?

Comment: Annotating existing values with extra data is more "comonadic" than "monadic": http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad.html http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad-Env-Class.html notice that the 2-tuple, the simplest way  of annotating a value, has `Comonad ((,) e)` and `ComonadEnv e ((,) e)` instances. In practice, perhaps it's just simpler to use a record.

Comment: @jberryman yes, I guess I should have asked myself that question. There's nothing special here, just needs to carry the extra data along. As danidiaz pointed out, maybe a record is the right way to do this. What I was hoping for is a de facto standard for carrying an arbitrary payload along with a vector of coordinates. I imagined there might be a large body of code written for it. The WithAny solution leftroundabout proposes may be the closest thing I've seen so far...

Comment: You might be interested in [this excellent article](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html) by sigfpe about cellular automata and comonads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you mean, but it might be this [what I've defined in the `manifolds` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Manifold-TreeCover.html#t:WithAny) (at the moment it's more of an experimental implementation detail, not a stable exported type):

```
data WithAny x y = WithAny y !x
```

`WithAny x y` behaves as a [vector space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) (more generally, as a [manifold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Manifold-PseudoAffine.html#t:Manifold)) in the same way as `x` does, but each value also has an extra `y` associated with it which is considered simply as a “tag” and not changed through the continuous-space operations. E.g.

```
  WithAny y x ^+^ WithAny _ ξ = WithAny y $ x ^+^ ξ
```

“Orthogonally” to those instances, the type is a monad in the second argument, with

```
  fmap f (WithAny y x) = WithAny (f y) x
```

(As danidiaz remarks, it's in particular also a comonad, I just haven't added that instance yet.)

Actually I'm a bit skeptical myself if the semantics of this type are really sensible. After all, points annotated with different discrete tags basically live in completely disjoint space(-sector)s, yet they can appear arbitrarily close through the vectorspace view, indeed you have `distance (Withany t x) (WithAny q x) ≡ 0` even if these points are clearly not the same.